# web service fail notification framework java

Tags: java, web-services, log4j

We are in development of an enterprise application. Its developed using java technologies. We are using log4j for logging purpose. The front end of our application is Web/Mobile applications and Middle layers is web service and from middle layer we are calling backed database and some other external web service. The backed web services are some times go down. When the backend services are down and the middle layer services are trying to access those services, we would like to have some email should be sent to some email accounts. Is there any framework available for this?
Can we do this by CONFIGURing SMTP on log4j?

Answer (score 1):

Sending emails on backend failure shouldnt ideally be the responsibility of the application itself.  It is the domain of operations.  You should look at BAM tools.

To make these operations tools effective however, what your application needs to do well is have a very clean exception handling and logging approach.  For e.g. each type of exception should be designated very specific **error codes** so that these tools can be pre-configured with these known **error codes** such that their occurrences trigger actions such as sending an email or SMS.